# Install image-displayer (Yii 1.1) in Yii 2

Tags: php, yii, yii2

Does anyone know how to install Yii 1.1: **image-displayer** extension in Yii 2? I tried to follow the steps [given](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/image-displayer) but the extension is not working. I am a newbie in Yii 2, please help me.

Comment: As I see this is for yii1,why you do not find something for yii2?I google this http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/757/how-to-use-imagine-crop-thumb-effects-for-images-on-yii2/  or http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii2-images

Comment: http://www.yiiframework.com/extensions/?tag=image

Comment: @dimis283 I was looking for something which can generate resized images passed from url on the fly

Comment: Another choice is to select a no yii related class. maybe searching at phpclasses.org http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-yii-integration.html